# Is Firefox User Agent Switcher enough to test if my site is cross browser?

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, user-agent

I found this plugin, for Firefox, on Google and it looks like perfect to test if my site works well on all major browsers. It changes the browser's user-agent and emulates almost all versions of all browsers on any OS, including mobile. Looks like perfect. My question is: can i trust 100% on this plugin? It really give me the same effect as if i were using other browser (ie6 for exemple)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It really give me the same effect as if i were using other browser (ie6 for exemple)?

No. Changing the `user-agent` string does not mean you are changing the browser's rendering engine - it just sends a different browser signature to the server.  The actual rendering will always be Firefox's, at the sites will always look as they do in Firefox.

See these questions on how to test sites in different browsers:

- [Browser testing - Ideas on how to tackle it efficiently](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15601/browser-testing-ideas-on-how-to-tackle-it-efficiently)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing

Comment: The IE Developer Tools can simulate IE6? It just shows IE7 to me.

Comment: @Rodrigo I don't think it can. See the link above for solutions that work

Comment: See my post for a link that generates screenshots with various browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It does not affect the rendering engine of your browser. It only **pretends to the server** to be a different browser, so if the server has e.g. a special IE6-optimized version it will send you this version instead.

Essentially, this is **mostly useful to access web pages that claim to not support your browser** by pretending that you have a supported version.

For testing cross-browser compatibility it is useless.

You can get free screenshots from a wide array of browsers at http://browsershots.org/
that is a very useful site, but won't help you test JavaScript interactions.